# PHP regexp how get all matches in preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I have string

```
$s = 'Sections: B3; C2; D4';
```

and regexp

```
preg_match('/Sections(?:[:;][\s]([BCDE][\d]+))+/ui', $s, $m);
```

Result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sections: B3; C2; D4
    [1] => D4
)
```

How I can get array with all sections `B3, C2, D4`

I can't use `preg_match_all('/[BCDE][\d]+)/ui'`, because searching strongly after `Sections:` word.

The number of elements (B3, С2...) can be any.

Comment: Try `(?:\ASections:|\G(?!\A))\s+(\w+);?`. See https://regex101.com/r/2sTJwE/1

Comment: This is tricky because what if you have multiple _Sections_ you want to have data separated. Otherwise, it's just a non-delineated list. If that's ok, I'd suggest a safer regex `(?:(?!\A)\G\s*;|Sections:\s*)[BCDE]\d+(?=\s*;)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(?:\G(?!^);|Sections:)\s*\K[BCDE]\d+~i'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/owjox4/2)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^);|Sections:)` - either the end of the previous match and a `;` (`\G(?!^);`) or (`|`)  a `Sections:` substring
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars
- `\K` - a match reset operator
- `[BCDE]` - a char from the character set (due to `i` modifier, case insensitive)
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/bN5Qig):

```
$s = "Sections: B3; C2; D4";
if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!^);|Sections:)\s*\K[BCDE]\d+~i', $s, $m)) {
    print_r($m[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => B3
    [1] => C2
    [2] => D4
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I read a lot of information about regular expressions, but I see the first time \K and \G. Can you tell where there is a full guide to regular expressions?

Comment: @user451555 See [`\K` reference here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) and [`\G` reference here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html). Basically, there are two comprehensive regex reference sites, https://www.regular-expressions.info and http://rexegg.com, but you may also check [SO `regex` tag description page] and [What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) for other nice resources.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex an explode will do fine.
Remove "Section: " then explode the rest of the string.

```
$s = 'Sections: B3; C2; D4';

$s = str_replace('Sections: ', '', $s);
$arr = explode("; ", $s);

Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/PcrNK